# Flot - Importing multi-series data from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I'm having trouble getting to grips with using a JSON file to populate my chart. At the moment, my function has a section that manually sets my dataset variable, e.g.:

```
var datasets2 = {
"01": {
    label: "Group 1",
    data: [[1391385600000, 98],[1392249600000, 99],[1393113600000, 98]]
},   
"02": {
    label: "Group 2",
    data: [[1391385600000, 98],[1392249600000, 98],[1393113600000, 97]]
}, 
"03": {
    label: "Group 3",
    data: [[1392249600000, 96],[1393113600000, 96]]
},
"04": {
    label: "Group 4",
    data: [[1391385600000, 89],[1392249600000, 93],[1393113600000, 90]]
},
};
```

This work fine. What I'd like to do is replace this with something like:

```
var datasets2 = .getJSON('example.json');
```

I know the code isn't as simple as that and I'm currently looking at how I could parse the entire JSON file as a string into datasets2 so that it works as normal. If anyone wants to know why the data is formatted that way, it's because I'm working on the toggle-series example provided with Flot.

Thanks!

EDIT

Thanks for feedback so far. I've tried using the command as per the answer below but still nothing. I'm wondering if the format of JSON file is out? I've formatted as per instructed by Flot but now I'm not so sure...

```
{ 
  "001": [ 
{ 
  "label": "first set", 
  "data": [ 
    [1391385600000, 98], 
    [1392249600000, 99], 
    [1393113600000, 98]
  ] 
}, 
  ],
  "002": [ 
{ 
  "label": "second set", 
  "data": [ 
    [1391385600000, 96], 
    [1392249600000, 95], 
    [1393113600000, 98]
  ] 
} 
]
}
```

Comment: so you are looking for JSON.stringify()?

Comment: stringify is what I've just started to look at along with json2. I was hoping that was the right direction to take?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading a json file use JSON.stringify(getFile("example.json"));
This will get the data same as you want. You can check it using console.log

Eg:

```
var datasets2 = JSON.stringify(readFile('example.json'));
console.log(datasets2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried with that code but no luck. I've tried reformatting my JSON file in line with Flot's requirements, I've updated the Q above.

Comment: There is an error in your json format. You have an extra , in 001 array[0]. the correct format is:

`{"001":[{"label":"firstset","data":[[1391385600000,98],[1392249600000,99],[1393113600000,98]]}],"00"[{"label":"secondset","data":[[1391385600000,96],[1392249600000,95],[1393113600000,98]]}]}`